# Java authorization library like "CanCan" for Ruby on Rails

Tags: java, authorization, playframework, cancan

Everyone I was wondering if anyone knows of any Java libraries that are similar to or offer the same functionality as CanCan (Ruby on Rails). Would love to know your experiences with them if any.

> [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)
>   is an authorization library for Ruby
>   on Rails which restricts what
>   resources a given user is allowed to
>   access. All permissions are defined in
>   a single location (the Ability class)
>   and not duplicated across controllers,
>   views, and database queries.

Bonus points if it works on the play framework (http://playframework.org)

Answer (score 3):

Here is one Example https://github.com/eltados/canny of something very similar? Has anyone got any experience using this?

Answer (score 3):

Checkout this lib:

https://casbin.org/

https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin

You can use a library in your application. Also, you can deploy it as a service and integrate your application to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I asked this question 9 years ago, but its good to see options to help anyone else who has the same query, Thanks again.

Comment: Casbin is an interesting solution.

Answer (score 2):

Does [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) not provide similar functionality? See http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations for examples of annotation-based authorization specifications...

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I will look into this as an option